# Communicate between local applications/Notify Running application

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# Console Application which communicates trough its Input and Output with another application. This isn't a thing that can be changed so thats the given part of the problem.

The other part is that I need a way to communicate with this Console Application. Google says WCF, REST and stuff like that but this to me seams a little bit overkill cause I only need to communicate locally to the Console Application.

I also tought of communicating trough a file with that application but than I would have to check the file in an interval for changes right? Also I'm not sure if this is performance wise the best solution? Also i would have a delay, befor the notification happens depending on the interval.

So what would be a neat way to communicate between to local applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this use need to implement socket communication in your application. Below link will give you an idea on how sockets works in c#

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm

Comment: Oh nice I didn't tought of such a "low level" solution but this would again include network protokolls beside the Headers of the network protokolls, wouldn't it this pass trough my NIC? What i found a few seconds ago (has to be after asking the question) is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx I guess this would be more leightweight but could also be a bottleneck but on the other hand sockets would have this overhead with the whole Network stuff. What do you think regarding this?

Comment: Using a file for communation between two application is not a reliable solution. Just think of a scenario what happens if the file is corrupted or deleted accidentally. Using sockets is always recommended and reliable for problem waht you are facing.

Comment: Yea that troubled me also and the fact that the file may be occupied by another programm or themselfs while both try to access it. I guess this means i have to wrap my head around working with network protokolls locally. Anyway i really appreaciate your quick and nice answer thanks! :)